# How do I delete a unfortunately named folder?

Tags: linux, rm

In an unfortunate series of events, I happened to create a folder named `--bindir=`. Thing is, I cannot `cd` to him because when I try to `cd` I get this message:

```
bash: cd: --: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L][-P [-e]]] [dir]
```

I also get similar messages for other binaries I am executing with that as a parameter, e.g `rm -rf`, `rmdir`, `ls` etc.

I know this sounds funny, and like those epic fail stories, but I would be glad if you could propose a fix, because I'm all out of them.

As a post of proof that I am not trolling or anything, here is a picture of that epic fail:
[image]

Comment: @Marco Oh wow. I searched for an answer, but didn't come up with these. How did I miss them? Voted to close it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rmdir ./--bindir\=/
```

or

```
rm -fr ./--bindir\=/
```